# Force mq to work only on drafts

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue, mercurial-phases

Recently Mercurial added phases.

Is this possible to restrict mq to work only on phase *draft*?

It should show a warning when I try to `strip` *public* changeset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of Mercurial 2.1, this hasn't been implemented yet. That release provided the basis for the phase concept, but (as you've seen) not all commands have been updated to take phases into account. We'll work on that for the next releases.

Comment: Well... I'm happy to hear that in future releases of Mercurial extensions will be aware of phases. :)

Comment: Some mq commands are aware of phases.  If you try use `hg qimport` on a revision with a public phase it will fail with the message `abort: revision X is not mutable`.  Also the rebase extension fails if you try to rebase a public changeset.  Both direct you to `hg help phases` for more info.

Comment: @SteveKaye: good points, we did manage to make some commands phase-aware. The support will increase gradually in the next releases, just like we now have support for revsets almost everywhere.